# Get time difference during a Grouped by query in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime, max, min

How can I make a difference to get time between first and last line during my SQL query ?

Datas are the following ones:

```
|--------|-----------|---------------------|
| EST_Id | EST_Token | EST_Datetime        |
|--------|-----------|---------------------|
|      1 |     vexef | 2020-10-17 16:13:01 |
|      2 |     vexef | 2020-10-17 16:13:21 |
|      3 |     vexef | 2020-10-17 16:14:31 |
|      4 |     vexef | 2020-10-17 16:13:51 |
|      5 |     fardd | 2020-10-17 17:00:11 |
|      6 |     fardd | 2020-10-17 17:00:17 |
|      7 |     fardd | 2020-10-17 17:00:19 |
|--------|-----------|---------------------|
```

For example for the token `vexef` I should have 50 seconds.

This is what I have tried:

```
SELECT *, TIMEDIFF(MAX(EST_Datetime), MIN(EST_Datetime))  AS diff FROM table GROUP BY EST_Token ORDER BY EST_Id ASC
```

The query looks working but `diff` returns me `0`.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to want aggregation:

```
select est_token, timestampdiff(second, min(est_datetime), max(est_datetime)) diff
from mytable
group by est_token
```

This gives you one row per `est_token`, with the difference between the earliest and latest `est_datetime`, expressed in seconds.